# Setting up GitHub on multiple computers for the same repository

Tags: github

I have setup a private repo from a windows machine to GitHub. I am now trying to setup access to that repo from the same username on a Linux pc. Are the instructions the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can set up a different ssh key and add it to your account or copy the id_rsa file.

Here are the basic instructions from GitHub http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/